# ceph rbd import hangs

Tags: ceph, librbd

My ceph cluster is 48 ms ping away from the ceph client. Rbd import of an 8GB image on the client hangs at some point during the copy and never progresses.  Ctl-C out of rbd import leaves the image locked in the cluster.  When I scp the image to the cluster and then rbd import locally the problem goes away.  I suspect a timeout occuring but cannot tell which config parameter to modify. Any suggestions?   This is ceph 15.2.13 octopus release

Comment: You can run with `--debug-rbd 20` to see where it will be hanging?